# Converting 2D shapefile to Equal Area Projection?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, ogr, area, geos

I have thousands of shapefiles with coordinates in lat/long (-180 to +180 x, -90 to +90 y), that contain polygons of which I wish to calculate the area.

I'm using the Python GEOS/OGR/GDAL API.  If I call the Area() function for each geometry, I'll get the 2D area, or the area on a Mercator projection (basically).  Since the polygons are really on a sphere, I want to convert them to an equal area projection before I calculate the area.  I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this on here.

Some reading of the documentation suggested there were functions somewhere in OSRSpatialReference to transform a point or geometry from one projection to another, but it wasn't quite clear to me exactly how to use this or what projection to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [org2ogr](http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to do the reprojection of each file and wrap the command line in a for loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.shp
do
   x=`basename $i .shp`
   outfile = ${x}_eqa.shp
   ogr2ogr -t_srs epsg:xxxx $outfile $i
done
```

You'll need to go to [spatialreference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org/) to look up a relevant epsg code for an equal area projection for your region if you don't know one off the top of your head.